# How to use ChangeFrequency in MvcSiteMapProvider and caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, sitemap, mvcsitemapprovider

I have an external class inherited from "DynamicNodeProviderBase" for configuring my Site Map,I am building my site map dynamically and the MvcSiteMapProvider is caching the data.What I am suppose to do is to clearing the cache data every 2 hours to build it again if something has changed,I set these codes but I don't know what exactly they are doing.so I have 2 questions:

1- How can I clear SiteMap Cache each 2 hours preferably using the following codes:

2- What are these following codes exactly doing:

```
foreach (var Something in Something.else)
{
dynamicNode = new DynamicNode();

 dynamicNode.ChangeFrequency = ChangeFrequency.Hourly;
 dynamicNode.UpdatePriority = UpdatePriority.Normal;

 //  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["dynamicNode"] = dynamicNode;

yield return dynamicNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I clear SiteMap Cache each 2 hours?

Set the cache duration to 120 minutes

### Internal DI

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_CacheDuration" value="120"/>
</appSettings>
```

### External DI

```
TimeSpan absoluteCacheExpiration = TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
```

> What are `ChangeFrequency` and `UpdatePriority`?

These settings are for the XML sitemap endpoint that by default is hosted at `/sitemap.xml`. The [sitemap protocol](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) explains exactly what they are for.

Comment: I do appreciate for your response,it was really helpful